# How is propane stove thermostat supposed to work? [Quadrafire Grand Bay DV40]

Tags: thermostat, stove, propane

The home we bought came with a propane stove, with markings Quadrafire Grand Bay DV40.  The stove is connected with a simple two-wire (non-powered) bimetal thermostat switch.

How is the thermostat supposed to work on the stove.  By reading the [manual](https://downloads.hearthnhome.com/installManuals/250_3681.pdf) (which by the looks of the illustrations seems to be a manual for my stove), it seems that the thermostat operates when the burner switch is in the "off" position.  If the burner switch is in the "on" position, the switch overrides the thermostat. At least, that's how I read the manual.

Now the issue is that I'd like the stove thermostat to actually work, since this stove is critical to maintaining the room temperature in the house.  We do also have a fireplace and a mini-split system, but (1) the fireplace can not be temperature regulated and (2) the mini split can only make the home lukewarm.

What I observe is something part-way.  When the stove is heating, the thermostat is set to its highest setting and the burner switch is "off", I can turn the burner flames off by lowering the thermostat temperature setting until a "click" is heard.  So far so good.

However, once I set the thermostat back to the highest setting, the stove flames do not turn on again. I am not sure how fast the flames should react to the thermostat, so I'm unsure if the thermostat is working as intended or not.  The manual doesn't say much about thermostat troubleshooting, and frankly I am not surprised: there hardly seems to be much there to go wrong.

Since I did my tests late in the evening, I only spared some 5 minutes to wait for the flames to turn back on, so I don't know if there is some sort of a holding period minimum.

So, this is a question for the knowledgeable: how fast is the stove supposed to react to the thermostat setting?  Is the stove behavior that I am observing at all normal and expected, or should I have it looked at?  Anything that I can do myself here?

Comment: This is something akin to a woodstove, only propane-powered, right?

Comment: When you used an external thermostat, did you use a specific thing called a **millivolt thermostat**?  Or did  you grab J random thermostat as normally used with gas furnaces? Does your thermostat have any smarts at all to it?

Comment: On propane stove: the stove burns propane gas to generate heat.  The same manufacturer produces wood stoves as well as pellet stoves, which I have not seen so can not comment on how sufficiently similar they are.  On thermostat: it is a millivolt thermostat, I know this because it is not independently powered - there are only two sensing wires that go into it, and the thermostat itself is a bimetal spring only, with mechanical linkage allowing you to set the tension (and thus, temperature).